# Webscrape Span tag (python bs4)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to learn to webscrape but cant get the code right any suggestions?

I want it to return the name of product and price but it returns

```
Amira Spandex Abaya <span class="product-price">579 kr</span>
Selena Abaya <span class="product-price">579 kr</span>
....
```

I tried change the code to:

| in | out | error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| price=product.find("span", class_="product-price").span.text | - | 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' |
| price=product.find("span", class_="product-price").text | Amira Spandex Abaya 579 kr | (what I want but doesn´t return all products) |
| print(title, price.text) | Amira Spandex Abaya 579 kr | (what I want but doesn´t return all products) |

my current code is

```
#pip install bs4 & requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

    #Load webpage to scrape
url = "https://www.tahara.se/dam/abaya"

source = requests.get (url)


    #convert bs4 object
soup = bs(source.text,"html.parser")

    #print out HTML

    #print(soup.prettify())

    #Run code

products = soup.findAll("div", class_ ="col-md-4 col-12 product")

#print(len(products))

for product in products:
    title=product.find("h2", class_="producttitle-font-size").a.text
    price=product.find("span", class_="product-price")
    
    
    print(title, price)
```

trying to extract from

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-12 product" data-pid="6792" data-s-price="579.00" data-s-title="Amira Spandex Abaya" data-s-sortcount="1">
    <div class="position-relative text-left">
        <h2 class="producttitle-font-size">
            <a class="color-text-base" href="/dam/amira-spandex-abaya">Amira Spandex Abaya</a>
        </h2>
        <span class="opacity-7 text-base">
            <span class="product-price">579 kr</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have almost working code, just get a text from the price tag (if exists):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.tahara.se/dam/abaya"
source = requests.get (url)
soup = bs(source.text,"html.parser")

products = soup.findAll("div", class_ ="col-md-4 col-12 product")

all_data = []
for product in products:
    title=product.find("h2", class_="producttitle-font-size").a.text
    price=product.find("span", class_="product-price")
    if price:
        price = price.text.replace(' kr', '')
    else:
        price = '-'
    all_data.append((title, price))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=['name', 'price'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       name  price
0       Amira Spandex Abaya    579
1              Selena Abaya    579
2             Senada Kimono    789
3              Saliha Abaya    884
4       Simone Abaya | Lila    429
5       Simone Abaya | Oliv    429
6      Simone Abaya | Svart      -
7                Zoya Abaya  1 469
8               Farah Abaya    589
9       Naila Abaya | Black    589
10  Eshaal Abaya | Marinblå      -
11     Eshaal Abaya | Svart    879
12    Amara Abaya | Mullvad    879
13      Amara Abaya | Svart    879
14       Salina Abaya Svart    429
15        Salina Abaya Lila    429
16              Inaya Abaya      -
17     Salina Abaya Mörkgrå    429
18       Salina Abaya Beige    429
19    Salina Abaya Marinblå    429
```